# How to tell a JSON schema is compatible with another in Java?

Tags: java, json, jsonschema

For example, I have a JSON schema looks as following:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "billing_address": { "$ref": "#/definitions/address" },
    "shipping_address": { "$ref": "#/definitions/address" }
  }

  "definitions": {
    "address": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "street_address": { "type": "string" },
        "city":           { "type": "string" },
        "state":          { "type": "string" }
      }, 
      "required": ["street_address", "city", "state"]
    }
  }
}
```

This schema indicate an object with two vairable **billing_address** and **shipping_address**, both of them are of type **address**, which contains three properties: **street_address**, **city** and **state**.

Now I got another "larger" schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "billing_address": { "$ref": "#/definitions/address" },
    "shipping_address": { "$ref": "#/definitions/address" },
    "new_address": { "$ref": "#/definitions/address" }
  }

  "definitions": {
    "address": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "street_address": { "type": "string" },
        "city":           { "type": "string" },
        "state":          { "type": "string" },
        "zip_code":       { "type": "string" }
      }, 
      "required": ["street_address", "city", "state"]
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, I added a new property **new_address** into the schema, and in **address** there is a new property called **zip_code**, which is **not a required property**.

So if I created an object from the old JSON schema, it should also be available for the new JSON schema. In this case, we will call the new schema is compatible with the old one. (In another word, the new schema is extension of the old one, but no modification.)

The question is how can I judge if a schema is compatible with another in Java? Complicated case should also be taken care, for example "minimum" property for a number field.

Comment: json is schema free. You will have to implement your own json validator. But this is not realy nice...

Comment: Not a solution, but just wanna bring up some news that there's a draft proposal from Snowplow called [SchemaVer](https://snowplow.io/blog/introducing-schemaver-for-semantic-versioning-of-schemas/#schemaver). This means in future, there might be a way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just test it. In my current project, I am writing following contract tests:

1) having Java domain object, I serialize it to JSON and compare it to reference JSON data. I use https://github.com/skyscreamer/JSONassert for comparing two JSON strings.
For reference JSON data, you need to use 'smaller schema' object.

2) having sample JSON data, I deserialize it to my domain object, and verify if deserialization was succesfull. I compare deserialization result with model object. For sample JSON data, you shoud use your 'larger schema' object.
This test verifies if 'larger schema' JSON data is backward compatible with your 'smaller schema' domain.

I write those test at each level of my domain model -one for top-level object, and another one for each non-trivial nested object. That requires more test code and more JSON sample data, but gives much better confidence. If something fails, error messages will be fine-tuned, you will know exactly what level of hierarchy is broken (JSONAssert error messages may have many errors and be non trivial to read for deeply nested object hierarchies). So it's a trade-off between 
* time spend to maintain test code and data
* quality of error messages

Such tests are fast- they need just JSON serialization/deserialization.

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract will help you writing contract test for REST APIs, messaging, etc- but for simple cases procedure I given above may be good enough